# Native "Select" HTML element is not working on browser device mode

Tags: html, web, frontend

Is there a good fix for the `select` element to work on browser emulation mode.
Open http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select in emulation mode and the dropdown is not working in Chrome.

Comment: what tool are you using to emulate Chrome? it works fine in the real Chrome browser.

Comment: @Woodrow Barlow what do you mean what tool?  f12 > toggle device toolbar > dropdown on the page

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your problem. i thought you were using a tool to emulate Chrome, rather than using Chrome to emulate a device. what settings are you using in Chrome's emulator?